# Modifying and Replacing Quoted Substrings within a string

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

I am working on a language translation project and am stuck somewhere in the middle.

I have situation where there is a string like

```
print "$Hi $There","$Welcome $Aboard"
```

and I want to get

```
print "Hi There", "Welcome Aboard"
```

i.e. extract the quoted substrings, strip the '$' and replace the original with the new substrings.

I am able to extract and change the quoted substrings but when I try to replace them in the original one, it doesn't work. To show you the sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "print \"\$Hi \$There\",\"\$Welcome \$Aboard\"";
print "Before:\n$str\n";
my @quoted = $str =~ m/(\".*?\")/g; #Extract all the quoted strings
foreach my $subStr (@quoted)
{
  my $newSubStr = $subStr;
  $newSubStr =~ s/\$//g;    #Remove all the '$'

  $str =~ s/$subStr/$newSubStr/g;   #Replace the string**::Doesn't work**
}
print "After:\n$str\n";
```

I have no idea as to why the substitution fails. Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `\Q` and `\E` in the regex. Your code works like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "print \"\$Hi \$There\",\"\$Welcome \$Aboard\"";
print "Before:\n$str\n";
my @quoted = $str =~ m/(\".*?\")/g; #Extract all the quoted strings
foreach my $subStr (@quoted)
{
  my $newSubStr = $subStr;
  $newSubStr =~ s/\$//g;    #Remove all the '$'

  $str =~ s/\Q$subStr\E/$newSubStr/g;   # Notice the \Q and \E
}
print "After:\n$str\n";
```

---

What was happening was that your `$subStr` look like this for example: `"$Hi $There"`

I'm not sure if it was interpreting `$Hi` and `$There` as variables, but it wasn't matching the literal string like you wanted. You can read about `\Q` and `\E` in the [quotemeta docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly.
I am not interpreting '$Hi' etc...For the translation of python code to perl, it's a crude intermediary parsing step where I place '$' in front of every word and then strip it off from the keywords, strings etc. 

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : As you want to extract the substrings present in the double quotes and strip $ in that double quotes . You can try below code

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "print \"\$Hi \$There\",\"\$Welcome \$Aboard\"";
print "Before:\n$str\n";

while($str =~ m/(\"[^\"]*\")/isg) #Extract all the quoted strings
 {
      $str =~ s/\$//isg; # Strip $ from $str
    }
print "After:\n$str\n";
```

**Perl One liner code:**

```
perl -0777 -lne "if($_ =~ m/\".*?\"/isg) {$_ =~ s/\$//isg; print $_;} else { print $_;}" Inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\$(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Try this.This will replace `$` only if it is between `"` and `"`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/61

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is because you aren't using [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) on your literal values in the LHS of your regex, and so special characters like `$` aren't being escaped.

However, you're using the wrong tools to begin with.

If you're tempted to match first using [`m//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) and then replace using [`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html), then most likely you need to be using a replace block using the [`/e` Modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) so that you can execute code in the RHS.

The following does a search and replace like you're trying.  Note, how I only created new values for 3 of the 4 variables, and also included a variable outside of double quotes to show how it isn't replaced:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %substitute = (
    '$Hi'     => 'Bye',
    '$There'  => 'Somewhere',
    '$Aboard' => 'Away',
);

my $str = 'print "$Hi $There","$Welcome $Aboard", $Hi';

$str =~ s{(".*?")}{
    (my $quoted = $1) =~ s{(\$\w+)}{
        $substitute{$1} || $1
    }eg;
    $quoted
}eg;

print "$str\n";
```

Outputs:

```
print "Bye Somewhere","$Welcome Away", $Hi
```

If your intention is to be parsing Perl code though, then you probably should be using [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI).  You can check [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1733163+%5Bperl%5D+PPI) for some examples of using the module.